# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LoginPage' available as request attribute

Tags: java

this is my jsp page

```
<form:form action="LoginSubmit" modelAttribute="LoginPage" method="POST" >
  <!-- UserName :<input type="text" name="username"> -->
  <form:input path="username" />
  <form:errors path="username"/>
  Password : <form:password path="password"/>
  <form:errors path="password"/>  
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form:form>
```

and Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/LoginSubmit")
public String LoginSubmit(@ModelAttribute("LoginPage") LoginForm LoginPage,Model      model,BindingResult result){
    System.out.println("Login data has been submitted....");
    return "success";
}
```

When i am running the program then it is throwing the error like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LoginPage' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(login_jsp.java:200)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: When is the error coming? Is it at the time of displaying login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller method which displays your login page you have to add LoginForm to the model as model attribute, your controller method which return login page may look like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showLogin")
public String showLogin(Model model) {
  LoginForm LoginPage = new LoginForm();
  model.addAttribute("LoginPaeg", LoginPage);
  return "loginPage";
 }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is because before the server return this .jsp, there is no method which bind the `modelAttribute "LoginPage"`.

What's your method that return this view? Or you are using this .jsp directly?

If you are using this page directly as default homepage, you need to modify your controller, and add a method, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)//depends on your servlet configuration 
public final String getIndex(BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
     LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
     /*just remember to use model.addAttribute("LoginPage", loginForm)*/
     model.addAttribute("LoginPage", loginForm);
     return "index";
}
```

for my example, you need configuration in the web.xml like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And you can call it by:

```
server/projectName/index.do
```

Comment: as a newbie who recently learned a littel bit spring... sure this the problem